# access steam web API using AJAX Jquery

Tags: ajax, api, steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I want to try and get data from an API but I am getting

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I cant change the content of API so I cant use `JSONP`

These are all I tried so far:

```js
$.getJSON('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v2/?key=keyhere&format=json&steamids=76561197970938759', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

```js
$.get("http://www.api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v2/?key=keyhere&format=json&steamids=76561197970938759", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v2/?key=keyhere&format=json&steamids=76561197970938759',
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {

    console.log(data)
  }


});
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if the server didn't enabled cross origin request in their headers, the browser will just not accept making an ajax call to it if you're on a different domain.

You could use your server to get the data and then send it to the client for example with [CORS-Proxy](https://github.com/gr2m/CORS-Proxy) or even use a website that does the proxying for you like [CrossOrigin.me](https://crossorigin.me/).

Comment: using `CrossOrigin.me.` would there be some security risk on my part or on the part of the one feeding the data?

Comment: @guradio `Crossorigin.me` would be technically able to see everything that go trough their servers, but `GetPlayerSummaries` doesn't really contain any private informations so the only thing that could be stolen is your api key, still not a big deal, if you have no other choice.