# Ajax call firing error event even though response seems to be valid json

Tags: jquery, ajax

even if I change the dataType to 'text', still the error event fires. I checked response data on jsonlint.com and it is valid json. Also status code is 200.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:"https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=29080075@N02&lang=en-us&format=json&nojsoncallback=1",
    data:"",
    success: function() {         

    alert("success");

    },

    error: function()
    {
     alert("error");

      },

     dataType:'json'
  });
```

Comment: If you check the console you'll see this error: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`. You're being blocked by the Same Origin Policy as Flickr does not send CORS headers with the response. This means you cannot do what you require using JS code alone. Closing as a duplicate.

Comment: You need to change web config to allow

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan what is the best solution for `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` ? if you dont have access to the page you are trying to access?my question is because of this [question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991377/access-steam-web-api-using-ajax-jquery)

Comment: @guradio It's never an ideal solution, but I'd normally build a server side proxy for the data. eg JS -> your server -> remote API, and then back again. It's slower, but if you need live data then there's not much of an alternative.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan when you say `JS -> your server -> remote API,` what do you mean by `your server` part how can i do it there?

Comment: That part would be written in your server side language, PHP or C# for example.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i need a script in server to get data from the API? i see thank you rory

Comment: @RoryMcCrosson Thanks. This is probably a dumb question but if the same origin policy is to prevent me from accessing the data, why am I able to see the response data in chrome devtools.